# Wifi not working after updating 12.10

Tags: wireless

Recently I installed Ubuntu 12.10 alongside Windows in a separate partition with ext3 file format.

Everything worked fine when I installed 12.10 at first. But after I updated the packages (which  was around 70mb), my Wifi connections aren't shown. I can see bluetooth working fine, but I cannot see any active Wireless connections (i have checked the "Enable networking" also).

Comment: Please run the terminal command: lspci -nn. Please edit your question to add the details of your wireless card.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Comment: Have you tried turning it on from the terminal?

sudo ifconfig wlan0 up

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar problem, it was resolved by following the steps here

http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/10/how-to-fix-unity-and-wireless-problems.html

**WiFi Stops Working After Upgrading To Ubuntu 12.10 (Broadcom Wireless cards)**

You can fix wifi problems using two methods:

- Either connect to the internet via wired connection and run this command:

  `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

Then reboot your system.

- Or use the following commands:

  `sudo apt-get install linux linux-headers-generic kernel-package`

  `sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl* firmware-b43-lpphy-installer b43-fwcutter`

Finally, reboot your system.

If that didn't help, try these commands:

```
sudo apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source

sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer b43-fwcutter

sudo reboot
```

Comment: Worked for me too

Comment: This worked for me on a standalone install of 12.10.