# Wireless not working after update (Ubuntu 12.10) Dell Inspiron 1764

Tags: 12.10, wireless, dell, broadcom

The wireless has stopped working on my Dell Inspiron 1764 laptop after updating Ubuntu. I installed 12.10 from DVD alongside Windows 7 and everything went smoothly. Wireless worked fine, and the software centre gave me loads of updates to install - which I did.

Now when I start my laptop, the wireless doesn't connect.

I'm using the broadcom driver and have followed the instructions here:
[Wifi not working after updating 12.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/215397/wifi-not-working-after-updating-12-10)

When I follow the first set of instructions:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

It says 0 updated 0 installed 0 this 0 that... basically doesn't find anything it needs to do.

When I follow the second set of instructions:

```
sudo apt-get install linux linux-headers-generic kernel-package
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl* firmware-b43-lpphy-installer b43-fwcutter
```

It says `E: unable to locate package kernel-package`

I'm a bit of a beginner at linux, so I may be missing something. I had it all running on WUBI this morning, but now have moved to a proper partitioned installation I seem to be hitting roadblocks.

Any help much appreciated.

EDIT:
OK - got a little bit further - turns out I mis-typed one of the terminal commands.
Anyway - now it says wireless disabled by hardware switch - i don't have a hardware switch!!!! any ideas?

EDIT 2:
Fix it... I had to go back into windows and enable wireless there (???) and the switch it on in ubuntu... weird. I also went into bios and disabled the wifi function button.